# Dynamically pick the user GUI and UID who's running Docker at the host from entrypoint

Tags: linux, macos, docker, permissions

I have the following script as the ENTRYPOINT of my Dockerfile and therefore Docker image:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Setup permissions
data_dir="/var/www/html"

usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
chown -R www-data:root "$data_dir"

if  [ -d "$data_dir" ]; then
    chgrp -R www-data "$data_dir"
    chmod -R g+w "$data_dir"
    find "$data_dir" -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
    find "$data_dir" -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} +
fi 

# Enable rewrite
a2enmod rewrite expires

# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

Everything is running fine for Linux since the GUI and UID for most of the distros is `1000` (we're using Fedora and Ubuntu). Windows - I think - doesn't care about it, but again the script works properly and everything goes well.

The problem comes when I try to run this in Mac (OSX) since the GUI and UID for the first user is `500`. That makes the permissions not to work properly.

I know I can always change the values from 500 to 1000 but ....

Is there any way to get this from inside the script so this is transparent for the user?

**UPDATE**

AS per the answer below, this is how my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Setup permissions
data_dir="/var/www/html"

usermod -u ${UID} www-data && groupmod -g ${GUID} www-data

chown -R www-data:root "$data_dir"

if  [ -d "$data_dir" ]; then
    chgrp -RH www-data "$data_dir"
    chmod -R g+w "$data_dir"
    find "$data_dir" -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
    find "$data_dir" -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} +
fi

# Enable rewrite
a2enmod rewrite expires

# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

What would happen if I hasn't defined the `UID` or `GUID`? Is there any way to rely on default values as `1000:1000` (first created user)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is passing (optional) environment variables to your docker container that can be processed by your startup script.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  www:
    image: somenginx
    environment:
      - ${UID}
      - ${GID}
```

Then use the values of `$UID/$GID` in your entrypoint script for updating the user's uid/gid.

Sadly docker-compose does not provide the basic ability to reference the current user's UID/GID (relevant [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2380)), so this approach requires each user to ensure the environment variables exist on the host. Example `~/.bashrc` snippet that would take care of that:

```
export UID
export GID="$(id -g $(whoami))"
```

Not quite optimal but at the moment there is no better way unless you have some other host orchestration besides docker/docker-compose. A shell script that handles container start for example would make this trivial. Another approach is templating your docker-compose.yml via some external build tool like gradle that wraps docker-compose and takes care of inserting the current UID/GID before the containers are started.

Comment: This seems to be the right approach for now, only one question how do I use the ENV variable inside my entrypoint? As any other var? Meaning `$(UID)` for example?

Comment: Yep, it's just a regular ENV in the container. Be sure to use curly braces though, `$(UID)` would try to execute `UID` as a command.

Comment: To ensure `UID` has a default value of 1000: `UID=${UID:-1000}`. Just add it somewhere at the top of your start script before the variable is used. You may also want to wrap the `usermod` part into a if clause so it only runs when needed.

Comment: Can you add an example for this wrap against the `usermod`? I am not following you on this one

Comment: Only run `usermod` when the uid of user `www-data` doesn't mach: `grep -q "www-data:x:${UID}" /etc/passwd || usermod ...`

Comment: I cannot get this to work. Passing those values in errors out "UID/GID variable is not set default to blank string", i can only get this to work if I use a docker-compose wrapper script, which I hate doing. How did you all get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the user id with:

```
id -u
```

this returns on linux 1000 for the current user (normally the first because its your own system)

now you can make

```
if[id -u == 1000];then
usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
elif[id -u == 500];then
usermod -u 500 www-data && groupmod -g 500 www-data
fi
```

note: iam not sure with the syntax

Comment: this is not dynamically like the OP asked for... what if you run docker-compose with the second created user on the system, which would result in the id 1001..