# "usermod: UID '0' already exists" why?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

As part of my Docker image I have the following `ENTRYPOINT` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -z "${UID}" ]; then
    uid=1000;
else
    uid=${UID};
fi

if [ -z "${GID}" ]; then
    gid=1000;
else
    gid=${GID};
fi

echo "UID: $uid"
echo "GID: $gid"

data_dir="/var/www/html"
usermod -u "$uid" www-data && groupmod -g "$gid" www-data
chown -R www-data:root "$data_dir"

if  [ -d "$data_dir" ]; then
    chgrp -RH www-data "$data_dir"
    chmod -R g+w "$data_dir"
    find "$data_dir" -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
    find "$data_dir" -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} +
fi

composer_cache_dir="/var/www/.composer"
mkdir -p "$composer_cache_dir"
chown -R www-data:root "$composer_cache_dir"

if  [ -d "$composer_cache_dir" ]; then
    chgrp -R www-data "$composer_cache_dir"
    chmod -R g+w "$composer_cache_dir"
fi

a2enmod rewrite expires

rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

The image compiles successfully. When I try to run the container by running the following command `docker run -it temp bash` I got the following output:

```
UID: 0
GID: 1000
usermod: UID '0' already exists
Enabling module rewrite.
Enabling module expires.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/public_html] does not exist
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Why my `UID` is `0`? I can't find where is my error here, any help is more than welcome.

**Update**:

Changing this lines on the script:

```
if [ "$UID" != 0 ]; then
    uid=1000;
else
    uid=${UID};
fi
```

Still making it to assign `0` to `uid`, is because of the var name? (I have rebuilt the image using `docker build --no-cache -t temp  .` so no cache is being used)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `$UID` in Bash expands to the current user id of the shell, and it's never empty, so `[ -z "${UID}" ]` is never true. So, you're setting `uid=${UID};`, probably `uid=0` if the script runs as root.

Then `usermod -u 0 www-data` complains because it tries to change the UID of `www-data` to zero, but that's already in use, and it doesn't do that without the `-o` flag. (And you'd never want to do that anyway...)

If you want to test if `$UID` is zero, use `[ "$UID" == 0 ]`. Or `[[ $UID == 0 ]]` in Bash. Or `[ "$UID" -eq 0 ]` for a numeric comparison, not that it matters.

(I'm not exactly sure if changing the uid of `www-data` to 1000 is a good idea in any case, you already must have the user for `usermod` to be able to change its uid. But that wasn't the question.)

Bash:

> `UID`
>      Expands to the user ID of the current user, initialized at shell startup.  This variable is readonly.

usermod:

> `-u, --uid UID`
>              The new numerical value of the user's ID.
>              This value must be unique, unless the -o option is used. The value must be non-negative.

Comment: I have made a small changes on the checking but `0` still assigned to the `uid` not sure why, can you take a look? I need to change the `UID` of `www-data` because of permissions. This is Docker, there is a host directory mapped as a volume, if the `UID` of the user running Docker is `1000` as it's for the first OS user and the `UID` for `www-data` is different in the Docker container then I will need to be swapping them on my side and I prefer to do it in the container.

Comment: This idea comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028098/719427) that's what I am trying to achieve here

Comment: @ReynierPM, bfft, I got the comparison the wrong way around. You probably wanted `if [ "$UID" = 0 ] ; then uid=1000 ...`

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue I didn't see it before